# some single send journeys fail to create an IER

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, email-tracking

We are using a simple de and a single send journey primary key is the contact id, the DE is sendable and testable and contactid is linked to the subscriber key.
When I send using a simple journey, just an wait, send email and exit with settings send immediate, no reentry. The mail generates an IER in our sales cloud.
however it I use the same DE, with the same email as a single send journey, an IER does not get generated.
This does not make any sense and I hope someone can offer some ideas or additional tests to figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IERs should work for both single-send journeys as well as multi-step journeys.

The list of things to check should be as follows:
-Lead/Contact Id should be the subscriber key in SFMC
-Select the checkbox 'send tracking results to sales cloud'

I tried it myself to ascertain the issues & in both cases, I could get the IERs in the Sales cloud within 1 hr.

Comment: I am doing research on similar issues in our system. Marketing Cloud is very inconsistent with IER's inside SFCRM. One response from a case I opened pointed me to this Know Issue. You can actually be kept updated and be put on a mailing list by going to this link and pressing the "report" button, this will keep you updated on the status of this bug!
https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000uYdmnAAC/journey-builder-emails-sends-not-creating-individual-email-results-for-every-subscriber-that-received-an-email My issue is that when I use the suggested solution the records almost never actual